# config.exceptions_app not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

I'm trying to render a custom error page for all 404 and 500 errors. So I have defined two methods not_found and internal_server_error in ErrorController class.

```
class ErrorController < ApplicationController

  def not_found
    #method which renders custom error page
    render_error()
  end

  def internal_error
    #method which renders custom error page
    render_error()
  end
end
```

and in my config/routes.rb I've included

```
get '/404', to: 'error#not_found'

get '/500', to: 'error#internal_error'
```

and in config/application.rb I've initialized config.exceptions_app as

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

But when I enter URL as http://localhost:3000/404 , I'm still getting the default page provided by rails and not my custom error page.

Any clue about what I'm doing wrong would be helpful.

Update:

I'm using ruby 2.3.4 and rails 5.0.5

Comment: Please post `render_error` method...also there is already has 404.html, 500.html.. in public folder remove them

Comment: @RajarshiDas I fixed it. Please see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805920/config-exceptions-app-not-working-in-rails/45819697#45819697

Comment: ok by default it should true in dev...

Answer (score 11):

Well it turns out that the variable `config.consider_all_requests_local` was set to true and hence my requests weren't being routed to custom error pages.