# How to use flash with error handler in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

For some reason, the flash message does not work when rescuing from an error.

routes.rb:

```
  get '/test', :to => 'pages#test', :via => :all
  match '/500', :to => 'errors#internal_server_error', :via => :all
```

application.rb:

```
module RailsApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

pages_controller.rb

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def test
    raise 'Test error'
  end
```

errors_controller.rb:

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def internal_server_error
    flash[:notice] = 'Internal server error. Please try again later.'
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

Visiting /500 redirects and renders the expected flash, but visiting /test does not.

Visiting /test redirects to root but ***does not render*** the flash message.

How to render the flash message when catching an exception?

Comment: This is a very good question. Now you got me curious if you might have this kind of issue -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805920/config-exceptions-app-not-working-in-rails/45819697#45819697